# Perl: How do I print the result of an Array of Hashes onto the body of an e-mail

Tags: perl, html-email

I have some data stored in an array of hashes, and I am trying to print the results onto the body of the email being sent. Results will print on the command line when the script is ran, however the body of the email will remain blank.

```
sub DailyInflow {
    my @inflow = SQLTableHash("select count(FOO), count(BAR), BAZ from table1 where days in (0,1) group by BAZ", $reportdbh);

    foreach my $inflow (@inflow) {
     print $inflow->{"BAZ"} . ": " . $inflow->{"COUNT(FOO)"}."\n";
        print "Total: " . $inflow->{"COUNT(BAR)"} . "\n";
    }
}
```

```
################### Send E-mail with CSV Attachment ##################

print "Sending Email ... \n" if $ENV{DEBUG};


my $subject = "Snapshot $reportdate"; 

SendEmail({
    FROM => 'user@email.com',
    TO => $args{EMAIL},
    SUBJECT => $subject,
    BODY =>DailyInflow()
        ATTACHFILES => [{
        Type => 'BINARY',
        Path => "$fullzipname",
        Disposition => 'attachment',
        Filename => "$zipname",
    }],
});
```

Comment: Your DailyInflow function should probably return something...

Answer (score 1):

Your `DailyInflow()` subroutine should look like this:

```
sub DailyInflow {
    my @inflow = SQLTableHash("select count(FOO), count(BAR), BAZ from table1 where days in (0,1) group by BAZ", $reportdbh);

    my $string;
    foreach my $inflow (@inflow) {
        $string .= $inflow->{"BAZ"} . ": " . $inflow->{"COUNT(FOO)"}."\n";
        $string .= print "Total: " . $inflow->{"COUNT(BAR)"} . "\n";
    }

    return $string;
}
```

But you can simplify it by interpolating variables within double-quoted strings.

```
sub DailyInflow {
    my @inflow = SQLTableHash("select count(FOO), count(BAR), BAZ from table1 where days in (0,1) group by BAZ", $reportdbh);

    my $string;
    foreach my $inflow (@inflow) {
        $string .= "$inflow->{'BAZ}: $inflow->{'COUNT(FOO)'}\n";
        $string .= "Total: $inflow->{'COUNT(BAR)'}\n";
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Dave, how would I take this data and place it into and HTML table? I'm stuck figuring out how to join my table headers with the data in the foreach loop.

Comment: @Brandon: Your original question had no mention of HTML. If you have a new requirement, then it's probably best to add a completely new question. I'm not sure where your `SendEmail()` function comes from. But I'd strongly recommend looking at a modern CPAN module like [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) or (even easier) [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer).